# Trying to use curl to get some information

Tags: security

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"identifier": "nicolas12", "password": "nicolas12"}' "http://34.159.31.74:3063/auth/local/" | jq , what i wonder is that when i run this command on kali linux terminal, it tells me "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10", so what should i do, i tried every kind of modification what i knew,so it keeps telling me that and i do not have any other ideas how should i modificate

Answer (score 0):

Your site isn't returning valid JSON. Get rid of the `| jq` and look at what is actually being returned.

Comment: yes i tried but still does not work, but am i able to see local storage on a site with kali linux terminal, i mean site runs on http and when i go in a storage from inspect elements i can check local storage, it is possible, but i do not know if i can from terminal

Comment: You said you're typing `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"identifier": "nicolas12", "password": "nicolas12"}' "http://34.159.31.74:3063/auth/local/" | jq` at the terminal. I'm saying to type `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"identifier": "nicolas12", "password": "nicolas12"}' "http://34.159.31.74:3063/auth/local/"` (without the `| jq`) and inspect the output. When you say "does not work," what precisely happens? What is the output from `curl`?